# What is the origin of the waypoint WORUM (neayby Houston)?

Tags: waypoint

I'm reading the book "Skyfaring".
There is a sentence "TQELA, WORUM, CRVZA (beer), CARNE (meat),
QUESO (cheese) for the city’s cross-border
culinary traditions"

What is the origin of WORUM?
Is it related to some food?

Comment: [Mezcal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezcal_worm)

Answer (score 5):

It's worm, as in tequila worm:

> Perhaps even more popular than the actual tequila is the ***[worm](https://www.google.com/search?q=tequila%20worm)*** crawling around the bottom of the bottle. But the worm, or gusano, actually originated with tequila's “lower-quality” cousin, mezcal, largely as a marketing ploy. The gusano is the larvae of a type of moth that lives on the agave plant.—[huffingtonpost.com](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/24/things-you-never-knew-about-tequila_n_5589092.html)

Comment: @user17606 anytime, be sure to press the tick button so the question would be marked as answered ;)