# What do aviation agencies do to make waypoints sequences more easy to remember to prevent navigation mistakes?

Tags: navigation, waypoint

[Inspired by this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32500/what-is-the-origin-of-the-waypoint-worum-neayby-houston).

What examples are there of waypoints strung together on airways or approaches which are funny or tell a story in order to help controllers and pilots reduce navigation mistakes?  **I'm not looking for individual waypoint names**, but connected waypoints.  For example:

> WONZA JOLLY SWAGGY CAMBS BYLLA BONGS UNDER ACOOL EBARR TREES arriving from the West into Perth.
>
> WEEEE WLLLL NEVVR FORGT SEP11 on the Freedom airway to Washington International.

Comment: @mins You found some in French?

Comment: @mins Nope - I'm guessing that names are never published in 
航点, ウェイポイント, የመንገድ ነጥብን or similar non-latin languages ;)  Your examples are great, thanks. You should post these as answers.  If the community let's this live, it will be a great resource.

Comment: One small example in UK is a pair of waypoints on approaching Southampton from the south: NEDUL and THRED. NEDUL also happens to be over the Isle of Wight Needles.

Comment: "Please give us a list of jokes" is not a Stack Exchange question. I'm pretty sure we (collectively) have been through this before on meta.

Comment: For airport codes, Ottawa to Zahedan: YOWZAH

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree and don't expect it to live but, worth a try ;)  I agree with the whole SE ethos but sometimes, just sometimes.  I've had the most fun reading these I've ever had on this stack.

Comment: @mins Changing the title doesn't help. If you want to ask that question as a separate question, go for it. But the current title is not descriptive of the question, which remains as "Please give us a list of jokes, albeit ones that might have a useful purpose beyond being jokes."

Comment: @mins Ah, I see in the last edit someone threw in the "to prevent navigation mistakes" line.  The original question and *all of the answers* are not about preventing navigation mistakes; they're about silly names.

Comment: Someone just close the question already.  It only needs one more vote.

Answer (score 21):

### Australia

- Brisbane / Melbourne [FIRs boundary](https://skyvector.com/?ll=-26.132425899087313,138.66430664500484&chart=304&zoom=1)
  `PUDYA SWEED LIPPS ALIDL CLOZA TOUDA PHONE`
  (*Put your sweet lips a little closer to the phone*, [Jim Reeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVaazgPlVhY))
- Brisbane [RWY19 STARs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB43H.png)
  `LEAKY BOATS SINNK` and
  `DRAIN PLUGG SINNK`.
  `BLAKA MOOVI` by the South.
- Gold Coast (YBCG) [SID 14/32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IlwA.png)
  `LUVLY MEETA MAIDS`
  (Lovely [meter maids](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meter+maid))

---

### USA

- Frederick, Maryland (KFDK) [RNAV (GPS) RWY 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wbzB.png)
  `PHILB DEFND GEEAY`
  (Phil Boyer, AOPA president, defends GA)
- Kansas City, Missouri (KMCI) [ILS/LOC RWY 1R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3j5j.png)
  `SPICY BARBQ TERKY SMOKE RIBBS HOTBI`
- Lebanon, New Hampshire (KLEB) [ILS/LOC RWY 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxTrm.png)
  `HAMMM HAANK BURGR FRYYS`
- Nashville, Tennessee (KBNA) [ILS/LOC RWY 2C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYreY.png)
  `LRETA JCKSN GRRTH`
  (Loretta Lynn, Alan Jackson and Garth Brooks)
- Orlando, Florida [COSTR THREE ARRIVAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jG0s.png)
  From LA BELLE Tacan: `DOWNN MOANS BIGGR`
  From BOXKR `ANDRO SETME`
  (I'm quite sure I missed some other)
- Palm Beach, Florida (KPBI) [Ivanka One Departure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0upQW.png)
  The various departure paths include
  `UFIRD DONLD TRMMP IVNKA`
  (The FAA scrapped this procedure and some of the associated waypoint names [in 2015](http://www.cnn.com/2015/07/09/politics/faa-trump-navigation-points/).)
  `CRYER UTLEY FINNS PYRUT AHABB`
  (Captain **Ahab** is a fictional character in Herman Melville's Moby-Dick; Jimmy Buffett song: A **Pirate** Looks at Forty; Jimmy Buffett song: **Fins**; Michael **Utley**: musician; Jon **Cryer**(?): actor)
- Portsmouth, New Hampshire (KPSM) [RNAV (GPS) RWY 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi600.png)
  `ITAWT ITAWA PUDYE TTATT` - `IDEED`
  ([I thought I saw a pussy cat - I did!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Tawt_I_Taw_a_Puddy_Tat))
- Salt Lake City, Utah (KSLC) [RNAV (GPS) RWY 34L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rryye.png)
  `HOAMR MARRJ BAURT LIEZA`
  (Simpsons characters)

---

Community wiki.

Comment: Also `DRAIN GUTTA DEBAY` (down the drain, into the gutter, and out to the bay), `VERRY TRIKI`, `DENIS LILEE` (Australian cricketer Dennis Lillee), at Brisbane.

Comment: Not to be outdone by their barbeque rival, KMEM has the BRBBQ arrival containing WHOLL HOOGG and BRBBQ SAUCC. But being from KC I must say the truth is on another arrival: BARFF!

Comment: As a note, try to upload plates & such to the Stack Exchange imgur (as images) so the links don't go dead. In particular for US procedures any links to charts or plates on faa.gov ***WILL*** break when the relevant document expires (they're removed to prevent people from downloading and using obsolete plates).

Comment: * "Lovely meter-maids", not "meet maids".

Comment: I found `DAVES STOOL` off Massachusetts.

Comment: @voretaq7 -- good point. Airnav has a redirector that can be used to get a link that always fetches the current plate, though -- can we piggyback on that?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject That's better than the FAA's plate repository, but if a procedure is cancelled I think they stop serving it (for obvious reasons)

Comment: @voretaq7 -- probably true :)

Comment: And one of the IAFs for the Portsmouth RNAV (GPS) 16: `SATAN`.

Answer (score 13):

I thought this was pretty creative.

> "Follow the yellow brick road" found on GPS 1R approach into Wichita, Kansas.

[image: KICT GPS 1R]